# CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y ignored

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I'm trying to build the last release of the linux kernel with the option `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO=y` and somehow this local version doesn't appear in `uname -r`.

I clone the official repo and used `localmodconfig` and the actual `config` file to generate the `.config` file. I set the value `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO` with `make menuconfig` and build the kernel. The new kernel boots without any issue. 
The same things happen when I build the kernel with debian and ubuntu.

I followed the procedure  :

1. `localmodconfig`
2. `make menuconfig`
3. `make -j8`
4. `make modules`
5. `make modules_install`
6. `make install`
7. `update-grub2`

Comment: Does  "git rev-parse --verify HEAD" give a valid output ?